# Cannot Access to Composite C1 Admin

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, c1-cms

I was finishing my first production site in "composite c1" and trying to post it on the production site on a windows hosting, I can not get into the admin panel. First a popup appears with a type I "alert" message with javascript much like the source code html text. loading and then freezes and does not advance.

Reviewing the logs it appears.

```
 System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
 'System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
 located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
 reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) File name:
 'System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'


 === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
 file:///C:/WebSiteProduction/Website/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
 C:\WebSiteProduction\Website\bin Calling assembly : RazorEngine,
 Version=3.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9ee697374c7e744a.
 === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file:
 C:\WebSiteProduction\Website\web.config LOG: Using host configuration
 file: C:\Users\Parallax\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG:
 Using machine configuration file from
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
 LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 LOG: Attempting
 download of new URL
 file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
 ASP.NET Files/root/6da1f297/5f8c113e/System.Web.Razor.DLL. LOG:
 Attempting download of new URL
 file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
 ASP.NET
 Files/root/6da1f297/5f8c113e/System.Web.Razor/System.Web.Razor.DLL.
 LOG: Attempting download of new URL
 file:///C:/WebSiteProduction/Website/bin/System.Web.Razor.DLL. WRN:
 Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
 ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing
 terminated. AttributeBasedApplicationStartupHandler | INNER    Error 
    2014-04-04 00:11:52.28   System.Exception: Failed to load assebmly
 'RazorEngine, Version=3.4.1.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=9ee697374c7e744a' ---> System.IO.FileLoadException:
 Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
 dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
 match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)   
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

UPDATE: 04/05/2014

Now appear this error.

[image: ss]

Comment: nobody know about this issue?

Comment: Do you have other asp.net sites working on the server?

Is MVC installed on it?

What version of .net is on the server?

Comment: No, first site on hosting, Really, dont know. Good Question....- .NET 4.00 Framework Integrated Mode.

Comment: Is asp.net 4.5.1 installed on the machine?

Answer (score 0):

Is asp.net 4.5.1 installed on the machine?

You need to install it to get elements of Razor working.

Comment: i dont know... i'll ask to hosting provider support

Comment: see the picture uploaded.

Comment: ensure asp.net 4.5.1 is installed and come back.

Comment: Is Required asp.net 4.5.1 to run Composite? :|

Comment: 4.5.1 is not offered on my hosting provider. How is possible that frontend works and admin not?

Comment: Try spinning up a free Azure instance server with the right components installed and see if that works. Then remove 4.5.1 and see if it breaks.